# Netty Bytebuf writeShort can't send to C client correctly

Tags: tcp, netty

I have tried to search the whole google to get correct ask. But I still haven't gotten what's going on. Here the problem:
   I have a tcp client written by C language. It's simple to send binary stream to a tcp server of Netty. First, make it simple, tcp server only echo the whole data from server to client. But it's weird that use Bytebuf "writeShort" into buff, client change the edian from BIG-endian to Small-edian. Such convert 0x007b to 0x7b00. I don't know if it is a bug. following the code:
   c tcp client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define HALO_HEADER ("halohalo")
#define DATA_STILL_LEN (14U)

typedef struct {
    unsigned char headerId[8];
    short package_len;
    short opType;
    short res;
    unsigned char data[100];
} halo_transfer_t;

void printfHaloStructBuf(char* table, halo_transfer_t *packet)
{ 
    int i = 0;
    int dataLen = 0;
    printf("包头Id: %s\n", packet->headerId);
    printf("包大小: %d\n", packet->package_len);
    printf("操作码: %d\n", packet->opType);
    printf("附加数据实际有效长度: %d\n",packet->package_len - DATA_STILL_LEN);
    printf("附加数据:\n");
    dataLen = packet->package_len - DATA_STILL_LEN;

    if(dataLen < 0)
        return;

    for(i=0; i<dataLen;i++) {
        if((i!=0)&&(i%16==0))
            printf("\n");
        printf("0x%x, ", packet->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void setUpPackageHeaderId(halo_transfer_t *package)
{
    memcpy(package->headerId, HALO_HEADER ,sizeof(package->headerId));
}

void setUpPackage(uint32_t package_len, uint8_t* data, halo_transfer_t *out)
{
    int i = 0;

    memset(out, 0, sizeof(halo_transfer_t));
    setUpPackageHeaderId(out);  //头部
    out->package_len = package_len;
    out->opType = 123;
    out->res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        out->data[i] = i;
    }
}

#define BUFFSIZE 1024 
void Die(char *mess) { perror(mess); exit(1); }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in echoserver;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    unsigned int echolen;
    int received = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: TCPecho <server_ip> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Create the TCP socket */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        Die("Failed to create socket");
    }


    /* Construct the server sockaddr_in structure */
    memset(&echoserver, 0, sizeof(echoserver));       /* Clear struct */
    echoserver.sin_family = AF_INET;                  /* Internet/IP */
    echoserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);  /* IP address */
    echoserver.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));       /* server port */
    /* Establish connection */
    if (connect(sock,
                (struct sockaddr *) &echoserver,
                sizeof(echoserver)) < 0) {
        Die("Failed to connect with server");
    }

    halo_transfer_t send_data;
    memset(&send_data, 0x00, sizeof(halo_transfer_t));

    unsigned char data[100] = {'\0'};

    /* Send the word to the server */
    setUpPackage(114, data, &send_data);
    printfHaloStructBuf("#####发送数据####\n",&send_data);
    //send(sock, (char*)&send_data, send_data.package_len, 0);
    int rc = write(sock, (char*)&send_data, send_data.package_len);
    if(rc < 0) {
        perror("Client-write() error");
        int temp = 0;
        int length = sizeof(int);
        rc = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &temp, &length);
        if(rc == 0) {
            /* Print out the asynchronously received error. */
            perror("SO_ERROR was");
        }
        close(sock);
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("Client-write() is OK\n");
        printf("String successfully sent lol!\n");
    }

    /* Receive the word back from the server */
    int totalcnt = 0;
    while(totalcnt < send_data.package_len) {

        /* Wait for the server to echo the */
        /* string by using the read() function. */
        /***************************************/
        /* Read data from the server. */
        rc = read(sock, &buffer[totalcnt], send_data.package_len - totalcnt);
        printf("Receive from server's count: %d\n", rc);
        if(rc < 0) {
            perror("Client-read() error");
            close(sock);
            exit(-1);
        } else if (rc == 0) {
            printf("Server program has issued a close()\n");
            close(sock);
            exit(-1);
        } else
            totalcnt += rc;
    }
    printf("Client-read() is OK\n");
    printfHaloStructBuf("Recv from server", (halo_transfer_t*)&buffer);
    //printf("Echoed data from the server len =%d, cnt = %s\n", strlen(buffer), buffer);

    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

tcp server of netty:

proto:

```
 public class Proto implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private byte[] headerId; //8 byte
        private short package_len;//2 byte
        private short opType; // 2 byte
        private short res;
        private byte[] data; // variable

        public Proto(byte[] headerId, short package_len, short opType, byte[] data) {
            this.headerId = headerId;
            this.package_len = package_len;
            this.opType = opType;
            this.res = 0;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public short getPackage_len() {
            return package_len;
        }

        public void setPackage_len(short package_len) {
            this.package_len = package_len;
        }

        public short getOpType() {
            return opType;
        }

        public void setOpType(short opType) {
            this.opType = opType;
        }

        public byte[] getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(byte[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public byte[] getHeaderId() {
            return headerId;
        }

        public void setHeaderId(byte[] headerId) {
            this.headerId = headerId;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String strHeaderId = new String(headerId);
            //String strData = new String(data);

             return String.format("[headerId=%s,package_len=%d, opType=%x,content=%s]",
                     strHeaderId, package_len, opType, Utils.bytesToHexString(data));
        }

        public short getRes() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void setRes(short res) {
            this.res = res;
        }

    }
```

decode:

public class ProtoDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(in.readableBytes() >= 14) {

        //System.out.println("1-->Decode is running, in length " + in.readableBytes());
        byte[] haloId = new byte[8];
        short package_len = 0;
        in.getBytes(0, haloId);
        package_len = in.getByte(8);
        int data_len = package_len - 14;
        //System.out.println("Decode is running, package len " + in.readableBytes());
        short opType = in.getByte(10);
        short res = in.getByte(12);
        byte[] data = new byte[data_len];
        in.getBytes(14, data);
        System.out.println(String.format("Decode is running, headerId=%s, package_len=%d, opType=%d, data=%s\n",
                Utils.bytesToHexString(haloId), package_len, opType, Utils.bytesToHexString(data)));

        Proto p = new Proto(haloId, package_len, opType, data);
        out.add(p);

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

encode:

```
public class ProtoEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Proto> {

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Proto msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (msg == null) {
            throw new Exception("The encode message is null");
        }
        //System.out.print("Encode msg:  " + msg.toString());;

        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer(1024);
        out.writeBytes(msg.getHeaderId());
        out.writeShort(msg.getPackage_len());
        out.writeShort(msg.getOpType());
        out.writeShort(msg.getRes());
        out.writeBytes(msg.getData());

        byte[] haloId = new byte[8];
        byte[] data = new byte[msg.getPackage_len()];

        System.out.println(String.format("haloid = %s, package_len = %d, opType=%d, res = %d, data=%s", out.getBytes(0, haloId)  
                ,out.getByte(8) 
        ,out.getByte(10) ,
        out.getByte(12) 
        ,out.getBytes(14, data)));

    }
}
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your protocol and c impl expects `LITTLE_ENDIAN`. If this is the case use:

```
byteBuf.writeShortLE(...)
```

Comment: Correct, after I post question and I have fixed this problem. The client is Little-endian. Thanks anyway.